# Courier New with font size 14 not working for command prompt on Windows XP

Tags: fonts, command-line

I have set Courier New as the font in the command prompt. When I selected the font with size 12, it works, but the font size is very tiny. When I change the size to 14, it won't work; it is set back to the default raster font.

Answer (score 1):

I duplicated your problem, and found that it does work with size 16.

However, I afterward had some error messages which seem to suggest that the support in XP for the Courier New font in Command Prompt is somewhat buggy. I had no such problems on Vista.